# Getting All Tweets From a Country Within A Time Period at Java

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

I am working on a project that I will get all tweets from a country that has tweeted within a certain time period. I will make a data mining on it after that(examining that how many positive thoughts are said for a certain pupil etc.). I want to use Java as programming language. However I don't know how to start this project. I made a search and I know that there is:

- Twitter's Search API
- Twitter's Streaming API
- Twitter4J a twitter API for Java
- Something interesting here out of Java : http://dev.datasift.com/discussions/category/csdl-language

Where I can start to get all tweets from a country(if it can be from a given state) within a time period. Some examples are like: you are giving a username and it returns the tweets if it is a public profile. I don't have the list of all public profiles. Should I handle that problem and how?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you gonna use Java Twitter4j is your best shot.

But you gonna have to choose a strategy for retrieving the tweets that you want.

You can either get the data from Twitter itself or get it from a Data Provider which has full Firehose Access. DataSift and Gnip are those providers which has full access to Firehose.If you want to use a data provider DataSift is the way to go because of its own query language which is pretty cool.

In case of retrieving the data by yourself.

- Firstly if you want to get the Tweets in real time you need to use Twitter Streaming API and Twitter4j makes it really easy to use it.But unfortunately Streaming API doesn't support country or language filtering.You can listen the Streaming API for the search queries that you are registered for.
- Your second option is Search API.Twitter4j also makes using Search API pretty easy.Search API supports much more filtering options.But there isn't any way to filter tweets for country.But instead of that filtering tweets depending on the **Language** is much more useful way to do that. E.g filtering tweets that are en,fr or so on.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Should I pay to get tweets from datasift and can I apply to twitter to be a firehorse?. When using datasift or something like that will I get all the tweets from the world whenever they tweeted?

Comment: The thing is that Twitter  Firehose is only accessible to selected partners.You cannot apply unless you are a very serious company or so :) If you want to access all the current and past Tweets just use Datasift.But if you want to use just the current Tweets use Twitter Streaming API though it doesnt have what you need for filtering.

Comment: just to add to Serdar - streaming api provides a very small subset of tweets as compared to the firehose.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the [search API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/search). However, the API doesn't allow searching by country, only by geocode.

Answer (score 0):

in Twitter4J

You can get location like this.

*tweet.getUser().getLocation()*

But it gets user's location input field.